How to impute missing values given a value in another row in R
I need to get the year directly above the null (the earliest file date that has a year value) for each person and then fill in the missing values with that year. I have a method that works using subsetting and assigning values, but it requires looping over the data and with billions of rows this is not feasible. Below there is a mock dataset which shows how the data is structured. Each ID has multiple file dates and may have several years associated with it. For file dates before 3/1/14, the year column is missing.
df <- data.frame(
   ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
   file_date = c("12/1/14", "9/1/14", "6/1/14", "3/1/14", "12/1/13", "9/1/13", "9/1/14", "6/1/14", "3/1/14", "12/1/13"),
   year = c(1979, 1965, 1965, 1965, NA, NA, 1982, 1982, 1982, NA)
)

In this data, the first two null values would be filled with 1965 and the last with 1982.

try your_data %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(Year, .direction = "down") from the dplyr and tidyr libraries

This may also help answer your question: Replace NA with previous or next value, by group, using dplyr

@jpsmith While I am pretty sure that answers my question, unfortunately I have to work on a server which does not have tidyr and I do not have permission to install packages. Do you know of a way to do this without fill?

As mentioned by @jpsmith it would be helpful if you included reproducible data. Having a true NULL values in your column would cause an error since it would be dropped from the column and would not meet the length requirements to be a valid column in your data frame (try running data.frame(ID = 1:3, Year = c(1992, 1965, NULL))). So in R, based on the punctuation (Null versus NULL) I am guessing that Year is character?

@LMc Sorry, I am not super familiar with R, but year is an int.

Since you cant use tidyr::fill(), you can try the following approaches using ave.
If you have access to the zoo package, this is quite simple:
# zoo::na.locf
df$Filled_Year_zoo <- ave(df$year, df$ID, FUN = zoo::na.locf0) # thanks to @G. Grothendieck


If not, a completely base R approach could be:
### Full base R
df$Filled_Year_base <- ave(df$year, df$ID,
                           FUN = \(x) {
                             x[which(is.na(x))] <- tail(x[which(!is.na(x))], 1)
                             x})

Result:
#    ID file_date year Filled_Year_zoo Filled_Year_base
# 1   1   12/1/14 1979            1979             1979
# 2   1    9/1/14 1965            1965             1965
# 3   1    6/1/14 1965            1965             1965
# 4   1    3/1/14 1965            1965             1965
# 5   1   12/1/13   NA            1965             1965
# 6   1    9/1/13   NA            1965             1965
# 7   2    9/1/14 1982            1982             1982
# 8   2    6/1/14 1982            1982             1982
# 9   2    3/1/14 1982            1982             1982
# 10  2   12/1/13   NA            1982             1982

(you of course can overwrite the year column, I was just defining new columns for demonstration)
